# neo4j database logical separation by customer

Tags: neo4j

is there a way to split the neo4j database to logical / physical units?

I would like to have separated databases for each customer, 
so a query results will not return invalid data from other customers by mistake, and also for performance reasons

if anyone knows a better / best practice design pattern, i'll be glad to hear as well

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you need a method to efficiently query your data depending upon certain labels. If that's the case, you might want to have a look into [indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html).

Comment: lets say that you have 2 clients: facebook and Nike where you host their data, and dont want it to mixed. how can i have single url to Neo4j (working with node.js client), and to do queries for Facebook's data, and then for Nike's data ?